# Heroku - Stuck Performing System Checks

Tags: python, heroku

I have been following the guide at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python, the only thing I have done differently is that I used `virtualenv -p D:\Python27\python.exe venv` instead of `virtualenv venv` since I have virtualenv installed in my Python 3.5.

Once I had continued to **Declare app dependencies**, I ran into a problem when installing the dependencies with pip;

`pip install -r requirements.txt --allow-all-external`

Gives me the following once it gets to the psycopg2 dependency:

```
Collecting psycopg2==2.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.
txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\seven_~1
\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-cdwueb\psycopg2
```

So I changed the psycopg2 version in requirements.txt from 2.6 to 2.6.1. Then all dependencies install correctly, and I am able to run `python manage.py collectstatic`.

However, when I run `heroku local web -f Procfile.windows` I get:

```
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | Performing system checks...
```

It stays in this state indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this problem too. It stuck when I ran: "heroku local web -f Procfile.windows" then I try to do it manually like this: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000" and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you! I finally got around to getting back to trying this again and your solution worked just fine.